# cron job per second

Tags: linux, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I run a cron job more frequently than every minute?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49082/can-i-run-a-cron-job-more-frequently-than-every-minute)

Hi , 
Did Anyone Answer me that

I want to schedule a cron job which will run at every second, can we schedule it

Thanks

Rahul Kumar

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/49082/can-i-run-a-cron-job-more-frequently-than-every-minute

Comment: I *knew* there was a duplicate somewhere, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: It was under Related on the lower right.

Comment: Hmm, wasn't for me.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't schedule a cron job every second.  If you need that degree of repetition, just make it a daemon with a very small sleep.  Chances are your job will take longer than a second to run much of the time, so you have to decide whether you really want to start the job every second, or execute the job repeatedly with a one second delay between runs.